# PGSQL: Query currently logged in users on a device

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given a database table like this:

| user_id | device_id | access | ts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 200 | login | 2021-08-17 05:40:57 |
| 2 | 100 | login | 2021-08-17 05:41:57 |
| 2 | 100 | login | 2021-08-17 05:42:57 |
| 4 | 100 | login | 2021-08-17 05:43:57 |
| 4 | 100 | login | 2021-08-17 05:44:57 |
| 4 | 100 | logout | 2021-08-17 05:45:57 |
| 5 | 100 | login | 2021-08-17 05:46:57 |
| 5 | 100 | logout | 2021-08-17 05:47:57 |
| 6 | 100 | login | 2021-08-17 05:48:57 |

I would like to find out all currently logged in users on a device=100.
Definition of a logged in user: does not have a logout event that is greater in timestamp than the previous login event.
User can have multiple consequent login events, but a single most recent event that is logout will consider that user logged out.

Expected returned rows:

| user_id | device_id | access | ts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 100 | login | 2021-08-17 05:42:57 |
| 6 | 100 | login | 2021-08-17 05:48:57 |

From above data set, I would expect to get user_id(s) 2 and 6; all of the other users have logged out.

What's the most efficient way to query this aggregate data?
Thanks

using PostgreSQL 13

Comment: Sample data is great, but you should also _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: I specified specific user IDs I'd like to get back - but I assume you're referring to specific rows I'd like to get back?

Comment: "implied timestamp".  "sorted".  These are not attributes of SQL tables.  If the table has a timestamp or sequential id, you should include it in the sample data.  Also give the rules for how you  know whether or not someone is logged in.

Comment: sure I can add a timestamp column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the last access for each user and then filter those with the last access equal to 'login':

```
WITH last_access AS (SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_id) *
                     FROM t
                     WHERE device_id = 100
                     ORDER BY user_id, ts DESC)
                     
SELECT *
FROM last_access
WHERE access = 'login';
```

Comment: I just ran through my cases - and I think this does exactly what I need, thank you so much!!!

Comment: You are welcome @tasha! Yes, my query solve your requirement, but if you can log out after a period of inactivity (without a log out row), you will need to modify the query.